How to handle : Error : image: Cast to string failed for value; NodeJS
So I'm working on expressJs and mongoosh connecting server to DataBase. For inserting documents I've created different file "data.js" and require this data.js to  index.js.Mainly error is about validation failed


My path of models and init(for initializing).

 **project
        ├───init
        │       index.js
        │       data.js
        └───models
                listing.js**



index.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const initData = require("./data.js");
const Listing = require("../models/listing.js");

main()
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to DB"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wanderlust');
}


const initDB = async () => {
    await Listing.deleteMany({});
    await Listing.insertMany(initData.data);
    console.log("Data was initialized...");
};



initDB();



data.js

const sampleListings = [
  {
    title: "Cozy Beachfront Cottage",
    description:
      "Escape to this charming beachfront cottage for a relaxing getaway. Enjoy stunning ocean views and easy access to the beach.",
    image: {
      filename: "listingimage",
      url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/hallway-of-building-LfqmND-hym8",
    },
    price: 1500,
    location: "Malibu",
    country: "United States",
  },
];
module.exports = { data: sampleListings };



listing.js

const mongoose =require("mongoose");

const Schema=mongoose.Schema;

const listingSchema= new Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
    },
    image:{
        type:String,
        // default:"https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/picturesque-morning-in-plitvice-national-park-colorful-spring-scene-of-green-forest-gm1093110112-293349147?utm_campaign=category_photos_bottom&utm_content=https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fimages%2Fnature&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=unsplash&utm_term=Nature+Images%3A%3A%3A",
        // set:(v)=>v===""?"https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/picturesque-morning-in-plitvice-national-park-colorful-spring-scene-of-green-forest-gm1093110112-293349147?utm_campaign=category_photos_bottom&utm_content=https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fimages%2Fnature&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=unsplash&utm_term=Nature+Images%3A%3A%3A":v,
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
    },
    location:{
        type:String,
    },
    country:{
        type:String,
    },
});
const Listing =mongoose.model("Listing",listingSchema);

module.exports=Listing;


So, my detailed error in index.js:

ValidationError: Listing validation failed: image: Cast to string failed for value "{ url: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/hallway-of-building-LfqmND-hym8' }" (type Object) at path "image"`
  ` at parallelLimit (C:\node_project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\parallelLimit.js:23:5) {
      stringValue: `"{ url: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/hallway-of-building-LfqmND-hym8' }"`,
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'string',
      value: {
        url: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/hallway-of-building-LfqmND-hym8'
      },
      path: 'image',
      reason: null,
      valueType: 'Object'
    }
  },
  _message: 'Listing validation failed


Your schema defines the field image as a String here image:{ type:String } but it looks like you are passing in an Object here image: {  filename: "listingimage", url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/hallway-of-building-LfqmND-hym8", }. Mongoose is expecting a String but you gave it an Object. Do you see the problem? If not read this to help you understand the difference.

@jQueeny Thanks for helping me out

Your schema defines the field image as a String here image:{ type:String } That's why the validation field, Because Here you will use image URL so schema will be imageURL. All other code is fine. Just define it as "imageURL" instead of "image" in the schema. imageURL:{ type:String }

//listing.js



    imageURL:{     //schema will be imageUR
        type:String,
        default:"https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/picturesque-morning-in-plitvice-national-park-colorful-spring-scene-of-green-forest-gm1093110112-293349147?utm_campaign=category_photos_bottom&utm_content=https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fimages%2Fnature&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=unsplash&utm_term=Nature+Images%3A%3A%3A",
        set:(v)=>v===""?"https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/picturesque-morning-in-plitvice-national-park-colorful-spring-scene-of-green-forest-gm1093110112-293349147?utm_campaign=category_photos_bottom&utm_content=https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fimages%2Fnature&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=unsplash&utm_term=Nature+Images%3A%3A%3A":v,
    },

